# Android Studio 4.1.1 resource linking failed

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I created a themes.xml file with this code:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->

        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

However, whenever I try to run this I get the following error:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{}],"original":"AAPT: C:\\Users\\hagel\\AndroidStudioProjects\\MyApplication\\app\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\mergeDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values-night-v8\\values-night-v8.xml:28: error: resource color/purple_200 (aka com.example.myapplication:color/purple_200) not found.\nC:\\Users\\$name\\AndroidStudioProjects\\MyApplication\\app\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\mergeDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values-night-v8\\values-night-v8.xml:29: error: resource color/purple_700 (aka com.example.myapplication:color/purple_700) not found.\nC:\\Users\\$name\\AndroidStudioProjects\\MyApplication\\app\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\mergeDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values-night-v8\\values-night-v8.xml:30: error: resource color/black (aka com.example.myapplication:color/black) not found.\nC:\\Users\\$name\\AndroidStudioProjects\\MyApplication\\app\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\mergeDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values-night-v8\\values-night-v8.xml:32: error: resource color/teal_200 (aka com.example.myapplication:color/teal_200) not found.\nC:\\Users\\$name\\AndroidStudioProjects\\MyApplication\\app\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\mergeDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values-night-v8\\values-night-v8.xml:33: error: resource color/teal_200 (aka com.example.myapplication:color/teal_200) not found.\nC:\\Users\\$name\\AndroidStudioProjects\\MyApplication\\app\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\mergeDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values-night-v8\\values-night-v8.xml:34: error: resource color/black (aka com.example.myapplication:color/black) not found.\nerror: failed linking references.\n\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AAPT: C:\Users\$name\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-night-v8\values-night-v8.xml:28: error: resource color/purple_200 (aka com.example.myapplication:color/purple_200) not found.
C:\Users\$name\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-night-v8\values-night-v8.xml:29: error: resource color/purple_700 (aka com.example.myapplication:color/purple_700) not found.
C:\Users\$name\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-night-v8\values-night-v8.xml:30: error: resource color/black (aka com.example.myapplication:color/black) not found.
C:\Users\$name\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-night-v8\values-night-v8.xml:32: error: resource color/teal_200 (aka com.example.myapplication:color/teal_200) not found.
C:\Users\$name\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-night-v8\values-night-v8.xml:33: error: resource color/teal_200 (aka com.example.myapplication:color/teal_200) not found.
C:\Users\$name\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-night-v8\values-night-v8.xml:34: error: resource color/black (aka com.example.myapplication:color/black) not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

Please help me fix this,dear Angels Of Stack.

Comment: Please provide full code of values-night XML file. Error is showing at color/purple_200, but there is no such color named purple_200 in the code provided by you and also please provide the code for colors.xml file too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your color.xml which can be found under app>src>main>res>values, you need to add the colors. so, let your xml file look like what is shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryLight">#64b5f6</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FFFF9800</color>
    <color name="colorTextPrimary">@android:color/white</color>
    <color name="colorScreenBackground">#fff3e0</color>
    <color name="colorTextHint">#E0E0E0</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#6200EE</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#3700B3</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#00796B</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#03DAC5</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from the logs, I think you are only defining the colors in the `values-night` directory and not in `values` directory. If are providing any configuration specific resources then that resources needs to be defined in the base resource directory.

For example if you define some drawable like `splash.xml` in drawable-v24 then the drawable `splash.xml` also needs to be defined in `drawable` directory.

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'